# Spring what is the easiest way to return custom Http status, headers and body to Rest Client

Tags: spring, rest, httpresponse

I would like to return to my Rest Client the simplest answer.
Only the:

- http status code **201**
- http status message **Created**
- http header Content **Type**
- http response body **Custom string answer**

What is the easiest way?

I've used to use `ResponseEntity` object this way:

`return new ResponseEntity<String>("Custom string answer", HttpStatus.CREATED);`,

but unfortunately, I can not simple pass http header in constructor.

I have to create `HttpHeaders` object and there add my custom header like this:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE);

return new ResponseEntity<String>("Custom string answer", headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

But I am looking for something simpler. Something that could fit one line of code.

Can Anyone help?

Comment: Use the builder instead of constructor. `return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE).body("Custom string answer")`.

Comment: Ya, agree with Denium

Comment: @M.Deinum text for help. It works. Could You post in as an answer that I could close post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already suggested from @M.Deinum this is the easiest way:

```
@RequestMapping("someMapping")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> create() {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
       .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
       .body("Custom string answer");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess this will help:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createData", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@ResponseBody
public String create(@RequestBody Object input)
{
    return "custom string";
}
```