# How to read the response of a successful Ajax call on jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that gets a small json string:

```
 <script id="local" type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('tr').on('blur', 'td[contenteditable]', function() {
        var that = this;
        $.post("ajax/modQtyModels", {
        modelId: $(this).closest('tr').children('td.idmodel').text(),
        qty: $(this).closest('tr').children('td.editQty').text(),
        ajax: true,     
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {   
            var myResult = JSON.parse(data);
            if(myResult['success'] == "true") {
                $(that).closest('tr').children('td.editQty').addClass("success");
            } else {
                $(that).closest('tr').children('td.editQty').addClass("danger");
                alert("No changes were made");
            }
        }
        }
);
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem is I need to read the response but it doesn't get me anything but errors. myResult['success'] doesn't get the value of the json string as I expected.

### Method

```
@PostMapping("/ajax/modQtyModels")
public @ResponseBody String modDevices(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "modelId", required = true) Long modelId,  @RequestParam(value = "qty", required = true) int qty) {
    Optional<com.ffuentese.model.Model> mdl = modelRepository.findById(modelId);
    if(mdl.isPresent()) {
        mdl.get().setQty(qty);
        modelRepository.save(mdl.get());
        return "{\"success\": true}";
    }
    return "{\"success\": false}";
}
```

**EDIT**: No luck so far. As long as I don't attempt to access data everything works just fine and if I check the response on Chrome it's there.

[image: Response as seen in the browser when data is not accessed.]

**EDIT 2**: The error I get when I try to access data:

> models:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of
>   undefined
>       at success (models:27)
>       at e (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at xb (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at Function.r.param (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at Function.r.(anonymous function) [as post] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:4:14657)
>       at HTMLTableCellElement. (models:22)
>       at HTMLTableRowElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLTableRowElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
>       at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:4)

EDIT 3: Solved after rearranging the elements of the AJAX call as stated in the accepted response edition.

Comment: What does `data` contain in your success handler?  Can you `console.log` it?

Comment: first after this line "success: function(data) { " add console.log(data); to see whats inside in the data

Comment: I just tried and got undefined

Comment: include what is in "ajax/modQtyModels" script which data came from?

Comment: I just edited it. The url gets that string and it works. The problem is I can't read it accessing "data".

Comment: `{'success': false}` is invalid json, keys need to be delimited by double quotes not single. Also you have `dataType: 'json',` which will tell jQuery to parse proper json responses for you. You should have errors on the console

Comment: try this `return json_encode(array('success'=>false),JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

Comment: I changed {'success': false} for {"success": false} and same with true but the problem is the same. If I don't try anything on "data" the ajax is executed but I need to access "data".

Comment: how do you know the `ajax` is executed and you're getting the string if `data` is `undefined` ? , add `error: function(err){console.log(err)}` after the `success` to see if the request is executed successfully or not

Comment: Because the change in the database is executed if I don't try to access data.

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37677600/spring-what-is-the-easiest-way-to-return-custom-http-status-headers-and-body-to) it helps you how to send proper header from Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

> **dataType**
>
> Type: String
>
> The type of data expected from the server.
>   Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).

you're expecting the server to return a `json` but you're returning a `string` , so either you remove `dataType : 'json'` from your `$.post` or you keep it and return a `json` from the server with `return {"success": true};` and if your return a `json` remove `JSON.parse(data);`

and when you compare the `success` , use `if(myResult['success'] == true) {`

```js
const data = '{"success": true}';

let myResult = JSON.parse(data);

if(myResult['success'] == "true") {
 console.log('here with quotes');
} 

if(myResult['success'] == true) {
 console.log('here without quotes');
} 
else {
  console.log("No changes were made");
}
```

**EDIT :**

don't mix the `data` you're sending with the `success`, use a `callback` instead, your `$.post` should be like : `$.post(url, dataToServer, callback, dataTypeExpected);`

try this :

```
 $.post("ajax/modQtyModels", 
        {
            modelId: $(this).closest('tr').children('td.idmodel').text(),
            qty: $(this).closest('tr').children('td.editQty').text()
        }, 
        function(data){ 
            //var myResult = JSON.parse(data);
            if(data['success'] == true) {
                $(that).closest('tr').children('td.editQty').addClass("success");
            } else {
                $(that).closest('tr').children('td.editQty').addClass("danger");
                alert("No changes were made");
            } 
        }, "json");
```

Comment: I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: I return a String from the server and removed the dataType from the javascript.

Comment: it looks like you're already getting a `json` , `data.success` or `data['success']` should do the trick, you don't need `JSON.parse`

Comment: It returns undefined either way. models:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
    at success (models:27)
    at e (jquery.min.js:4)
    at xb (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.r.param (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.r.(anonymous function) [as post] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:4:14657)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (models:22)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js

Comment: well .. i'm left with only one suggestion, i doubted it at first but .. check the edit

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to parse JSON manually, JQuery does this for you. So, just remove `var myResult = JSON.parse(data);` from your code, and use `data` directly.

Try this:

```
$.post("ajax/modQtyModels",
    {
        modelId: $(this).closest('tr').children('td.idmodel').text(),
        qty: $(this).closest('tr').children('td.editQty').text()
    },
    function(data) {
        var myResult = data;
        if(myResult['success'] == "true") {
            $(that).closest('tr').children('td.editQty').addClass("success");
        } else {
            $(that).closest('tr').children('td.editQty').addClass("danger");
            alert("No changes were made");
        }
    },
    'json'
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I get an error: "undefined" whenever I try to access "data". See my edits.

Comment: really ? that's exactly my EDIT more than 5 minutes ago :)

Comment: @Taki Hahaha...I suppose he goes into the wrong way. And this is "standard" method to use JQuery.post, may be useful.